# rails: stow away long method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have this method (50+ lines) in one of my models, I prefer not having to scroll so much and not losing my cursor sometimes because of its taking up so much space. I wonder if I can put it away in a separate file and sort of include it in the model instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it into a module and include it (mix it in) to your model class. For example:

```
app/models/my_long_method.rb
  module MyLongMethod
    def my_long_method
      ....
    end
  end

app/models/my_class.rb
  class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyLongMethod
  end
```

If your method really is that long though you might want to consider breaking it down into smaller sections as methods in that module too.

```
module MyLongMethod
  def my_long_method
    first_part
    second_part
  end

  private

  def first_part
    ...
  end

  def second_part
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer. Relevant link for the last part: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

Comment: Thanks Shadwell and Troeskn. One last question to clear one thing up: does the module .rb file have to be in the same dir as the model which will 'include' it?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to. It just needs to be available in the load path. If you put it in a subdirectory you'll either need to put that subdirectory on the load path or use a namespace. E.g. `module SubDir::MyLongMethod`.

Comment: I have just tried this, but I get the error: app/models/line_item.rb:4:in `<class:LineItem>': uninitialized constant LineItem::HandyMethods (NameError)......I have placed the handy_methods.rb in the lib dir

Comment: You may need to `require 'line_item/handy_methods'` at the top of your model if the module is in the lib directory. Under app/blah it Rail should figure out where it is but I don't think that works for /lib.

Comment: @Shadwell, You're right. I just searched around and found that Rails 3 no longer auto-load files in lib. Thanks again!